# How to "lock" static object in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Well, I've a situation, where in `Class A` I get "X DATA".
I want to store this "X DATA" in `Object X` one time and then make sure, the values of this object is not possible to change. (Set it once and forget about it).

My approach:

```
object X {
    var attribute1: String
    var attribute2: String
}
```

Obviously, as object attributes are `var` they are changeable in future. How could I avoid this? Is there a way to assign values (in some time..) and then lock the object till application is exited?

Comment: Will X be used before "X DATA" is available?

Answer (score 4):

You could use a delegate property

```
class MyProperty<T : Any> {

    private var value: T? = null

    operator fun getValue(myObject: MyObject, property: KProperty<*>): T =
            value ?: throw UninitializedPropertyAccessException()

    operator fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: T) = when (this.value) {
        null -> this.value = value
        else -> throw IllegalAccessException("Property already initialized")
    }
}
```

and then use `var` in your object

```
object MyObject {

    var myProperty by MyProperty<String>()

}
```

In the sample above, if you try to access `myProperty` before setting a value, an exception is thrown, but you could handle that as you wish (return a default value? maybe null?).

If you try to assign the value more than once, you get an exception as well but you could handle that differently, for instance, by simply not setting the value anymore so that

```
MyObject.myProperty = "foo"
MyObject.myProperty = "bar"
println(MyObject.myProperty)
```

will print `"foo"`

Comment: The problem of this method is that it is checked in *runtime*, not in *compile-time*. However, I don't think there is some compile-time checking method unless you use two variables -- both `var` and `val` -- which is also not compile-time checked while using `var`.

Comment: You're right, it is checked at runtime, but if you use `val` you won't be able to assign the value directly on the property. You could use a setter but the whole magic about one-time assignment property is gone then

Comment: @lelloman I'd say UninitializedPropertyAccessException is preferable for access before init.

Comment: thanks @PaulGeorgPodlech it is more appropriate indeed

Comment: @lelloman Your solution unfortunately doesn't work for nullable types. There is a thread about that topic with a solution [here](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/how-to-create-a-nullable-delegate-property/4628/6).

Comment: I don't see why that would be the case, I just tried by modifying return value to `T?` and it works

Comment: @lelloman With your current code `myProperty` has inferred type `String`. After your proposed change (you'll have to also change the parameter in `setValue`) it will have inferred type `String?`. If you want to delegate nullable and non-nullable types you will need a different delegate. That's what the link I posted deals with.

Comment: So the problem arises if you want the delegate class to work with both nullable and non-nullable types. Noted, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lateinit var attribute1: String` to tell the compiler that you will manage setting `attribute1` to a non-null value before it's used.

There's no such thing as `lateinit val` to "lock" the value as you say.

The [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html) have more information.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you make those properties final by replacing var with val.

> **var** is like **general** variable and its known as a mutable variable in **kotlin** and can be assigned multiple times.
>
> **val** is like **constant** variable and its known as immutable in **kotlin** and can be initialized only single time.

Answer (score 0):

You can't `lateinit` immutable properties in kotlin and `lateinit var` does not allow custom setters.
So my approach would be implementing the lateinit var behavior with a backing property, custom getter and custom setter. This is quite a similar approach to lellomans solution.

```
object X {
    private lateinit var backingprop: String
    var attribute: String
        set(arg) {
            if (this::backingprop.isInitialized) throw IllegalAccessException("Property already initialized")
            backingprop = arg
        }
        get() = backingprop
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I warn you! But you can use such example:

```
object Immutable {
    val immutableString: String = mutableStaticString ?: "some default value, just in case"
}

var mutableStaticString: String? = null

class App : Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        mutableStaticString = "hello duct tape solutions!"

        android.util.Log.d("ductTape", mutableStaticString)
        android.util.Log.d("ductTape", Immutable.immutableString)
    }
}
```